# Can't start a win10 app remotely

Tags: remote-access

I need to start a win10 app remotly.
What I already tried is:
for starters I used this path: shell:appsfolder\appname!app

using psexec to start the app doesn't work

same with powershell (over psexec as well as native ps remote)

also tried starting it indirectly from a .cmd file and .vbs file executing form psexec

all these command and files are working if executed directly on the client. But if I try to execute them remotly I get the error message path not found or it just nothing happening  and really nothing I checked if the appropriate exe file is running via taskmanager. Apparently there must be some issue with the name translation of shell:appsfolder over a remote session.